# grouping csv data under same timestamp

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that contains the following data.

```
created_at               hr         bp_dias      bp_sys      weight     
18/05/2015  12:00:05     57
18/05/2015  12:00:05                 79
18/05/2015  12:00:05                               62
18/05/2015  12:00:05                                            83
```

I'd like to get them all into one single line, like so

```
 created_at              hr         bp_dias      bp_sys      weight 
 18/05/2015  12:00:05    57          79            62         83
```

I tried using `pandas` groupby and tried grouping them according to the time stamp, but that didn't give me the result I wanted.

Here is the code I used.

```
  df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',parse_dates=True)
  df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'],unit='s')
  df = df.set_index('created_at')    
  df = df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month,df.index.day])

  print df.head()
```

Comment: You can just use `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',parse_dates=[0])` you shouldn't need the other lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) 'created_at' and call [`max()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html#pandas.DataFrame.max) and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index):

```
In [165]:    
df.groupby('created_at').max().reset_index()

Out[165]:
           created_at  hr  bp_dias  bp_sys  weight     
0 2015-05-18 12:00:05  57       79      62           83
```